# Manipulating Laravel html response just before sending it to browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-facade, laravel-response

What is the proper way to manipulate final output before sending it to browser? (laravel 5.*)

I have created facade

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response as ResponseFacade;
use Illuminate\Http\Response as ResponseHttp;

class Response extends ResponseFacade
{

    public static function viewMod($view, $data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {   
        $output = \Response::view($view, $data, $status, $headers);

        return some_manipulating_function($output);
    }
}
```

and in the controller action i use

```
return viewMod("my_view_file", array $view_data);
```

but i receive corrupted output (http response headers are added to/ prepended to html)

most probably \Response related __toString method behaves strangely

any ideas? (thanks!)

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: let's say i have some custom markups added to layout, views, variables passed to the views  (so they are hard-coded and/or retrieved from db) that i want to parse

Comment: @AdamZygadlewicz check `View::creator()` method to see if it's a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`AfterMiddleware`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) like below example from docs,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform action

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: might be a good start, thanks! but how to modify output? or how to replace view("....") with my own implementation? :>

Comment: actually you are perfectly right

`public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform action

        $response->setContent(modify_content_function($response->original));

        return $response;}`